# DRAM problem with an fit image of increasing size

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded, u-boot, yocto

I have a 512 MiB ram capacity on a proprietary board with the Zynq700 SoC. This corresponds to the address range [0x00000000,0x20000000].

I run a ram-based operating system on it and it works fine until I make the following change:

- I add the valgrind, gdb, gdbserver and strace packages to rootfs, without further changes.

Consequently:

- My fit image grows (~x2).
- I load by JTAG this itb from clobstart (which I have defined at address 0x10000000)
- I calculate the crc32 of the fit image on my host, and then using the u-boot crc32 utility from that RAM address to the size of the file the crc is identical.
- I proceed to boot and the kernel hangs on the message shown below.

It occurs to me that, pherhaps, I may be overlapping with something that is already loaded in that area of DRAM. I leave you a detail of my fitImage below for more information.

```
==> bootm $clobstart
## Loading kernel from FIT Image at 10000000 ...
   Using 'conf@1' configuration
   Verifying Hash Integrity ... OK
   Trying 'kernel@1' kernel subimage
     Description:  Linux kernel
     Type:         Kernel Image
     Compression:  uncompressed
     Data Start:   0x100000cc
     Data Size:    46423824 Bytes = 44.3 MiB
     Architecture: ARM
     OS:           Linux
     Load Address: 0x00008000
     Entry Point:  0x00008000
     Hash algo:    crc32
     Hash value:   3d108223
   Verifying Hash Integrity ... crc32+ OK
## Loading fdt from FIT Image at 10000000 ...
   Using 'conf@1' configuration
   Trying 'fdt@1' fdt subimage
     Description:  Flattened device tree blob
     Type:         Flat Device Tree
     Compression:  uncompressed
     Data Start:   0x12c460c0
     Data Size:    16036 Bytes = 15.7 KiB
     Architecture: ARM
     Hash algo:    crc32
     Hash value:   15b17b33
   Verifying Hash Integrity ... crc32+ OK
   Booting using the fdt blob at 0x12c460c0
   Loading Kernel Image ... OK
   Loading Device Tree to 07ff9000, end 07fffea3 ... OK

Starting kernel ...

Uncompressing Linux... done, booting the kernel.

Error: unrecognized/unsupported machine ID (r1 = 0x00000000).

Available machine support:
ID (hex)     NAME
ffffffff     Generic DT based system
ffffffff     ARM Versatile Express
ffffffff     Xilinx Zynq Platform

Please check your kernel config and/or bootloader.
```

Comment: Your image grows by a factor of 2 because of that additions?

Comment: @Philippos yes, just those changes, populate the rootfs with those utilities needed for development (`the size increases from ~21 MiB to ~46 MiB`)

Comment: Any idea? Thanks in advance

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41230606/cannot-boot-from-fit-image) help?

Comment: Thanks @MurrayJensen, but the solution has been to recalculate the entry and load property values in my its for the kernel and the fdt nodes according to my available DRAM size, the kernel size and the clobstart chosen to load the itb (zImage + dtb) by JTAG.